# Выдаёт ошибку TypeError: '<=' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int' При использовании функции asyncio.sleep в slash командах

Tags: python, discord.py

При использовании slash(/) команды на мут ботом в дискорде выдаёт ошибку:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Fenix\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 343, in _run_event
    await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Fenix\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\dislash\application_commands\slash_client.py", line 1202, in _on_socket_response
    await self._process_interaction(payload["d"])
  File "C:\Users\Fenix\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\dislash\application_commands\slash_client.py", line 1360, in _process_interaction
    await self._on_slash_command(inter)
  File "C:\Users\Fenix\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\dislash\application_commands\slash_client.py", line 1260, in _on_slash_command
    raise err
  File "C:\Users\Fenix\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\dislash\application_commands\slash_client.py", line 1255, in _on_slash_command
    await app_command.invoke(inter)
  File "C:\Users\Fenix\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\dislash\application_commands\slash_core.py", line 216, in invoke
    raise err
  File "C:\Users\Fenix\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\dislash\application_commands\slash_core.py", line 212, in invoke
    await self._maybe_cog_call(self._cog, interaction, interaction.data)
  File "C:\Users\Fenix\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\dislash\application_commands\slash_core.py", line 37, in _maybe_cog_call
    return await self(inter, **params)
  File "C:\Users\Fenix\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\dislash\application_commands\core.py", line 72, in __call__
    return await self.func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Fenix\Desktop\bots\InfinityBot\bot.py", line 844, in mute
    await asyncio.sleep(time * 5)
  File "C:\Users\Fenix\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\asyncio\tasks.py", line 638, in sleep
    if delay <= 0:
TypeError: '<=' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int'
```

Сам код:

```
@slash.command(
    guild_ids=test_guilds,
    name="mute",
    description="mute in all channel",
    options=[
        Option("user", "Intruder", Type.USER),
        Option("time", "Mut Time", Type.STRING),
        Option("reason", "Clause of the Rules", Type.STRING),
    ]
)
@slash_commands.has_role(862061269300936759)
async def mute(inter, user, time, reason):
    mute_role = discord.utils.get(inter.guild.roles, id=876733754591293450)
    emb = discord.Embed(color=discord.Color.blurple())
    emb.title = str(user)
    emb.description = (
        f"**Модератор:** `{inter.author}`\n"
        f"**Нарушитель:** `{user}`\n"
        f"**Время:** `{time}`\n"
        f"**Причина:** `{reason}`\n"
    )
    emb.set_thumbnail(url=inter.author.avatar_url)
    await inter.send(embed = emb)
    await user.add_roles(mute_role)
    await asyncio.sleep(time * 5)
    await user.remove_roles(mute_role)
```

Роль Мута Даётся, но не забирается. Прошу помочь в решении данной проблемы.

Comment: Как очевидно из текста ошибки, у вас time является не числом, а строкой

Comment: `time` строка? Может банально сделать `asyncio.sleep(int(time) * 5)`?

Comment: Да, спасибо. asyncio.sleep(int(time) * 5) - решило проблему.

Answer (score 1):

Как вы запускаете функцию, можно пример?
Задайте тип параметра `time` заранее

```
@slash.command(
    guild_ids=test_guilds,
    name="mute",
    description="mute in all channel",
    options=[
        Option("user", "Intruder", Type.USER),
        Option("time", "Mut Time", Type.STRING),
        Option("reason", "Clause of the Rules", Type.STRING),
    ]
)
@slash_commands.has_role(862061269300936759)
async def mute(inter, user, time: int, reason):
    mute_role = discord.utils.get(inter.guild.roles, id=876733754591293450)
    emb = discord.Embed(color=discord.Color.blurple())
    emb.title = str(user)
    emb.description = (
        f"**Модератор:** `{inter.author}`\n"
        f"**Нарушитель:** `{user}`\n"
        f"**Время:** `{time}`\n"
        f"**Причина:** `{reason}`\n"
    )
    emb.set_thumbnail(url=inter.author.avatar_url)
    await inter.send(embed = emb)
    await user.add_roles(mute_role)
    await asyncio.sleep(time * 5)
    await user.remove_roles(mute_role)
```